# NMH API: how to write a script to send a message that is in a draft folder?

Tags: email

I'm trying to use nmh's "draftfolder" feature to queue outgoing mail for later delivery.
The key step I don't know how to implement is how to write a program that will send a message from a draft folder.

Here's the workflow I'm trying to achieve:

1. I compose a message using the `comp` or `repl` programs, and I quit with the message unsent, leaving it in the "draft folder" `+delay4`.
2. Sometime after four hours have elapsed, a cron job comes along and sends the message, removing it from the draft folder.

Here are the difficulties I'm having with existing MH commands

- The `comp -use` command can send an existing message from a draft folder, but it requires interaction.  I want to do this noninteractively from a cron job, and I'd prefer not to try to write an expect script.  I tried

  ```
  comp -use -noedit -nowhatnowproc
  ```

  but that did not send the message.  I don't know if some kind of alternate `whatnow` program would do the trick.
- The `send` and `post` commands look promising, but both expect to operate on *files*, not messages in folders.  Maybe `send` followed by `rmm` works, maybe it doesn't.
- I could go direct to sendmail, but then I would have to figure out whether to run `mhbuild` or not.   And I would seem to have the same issue of needing to remove the message from the folder.

My question is **how can I use the MH API in a script to send a message that is sitting in a draft folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM.

The `send` command's `-draftfolder` option makes it work on messages, not files.
Perfect for what I want.  If you want to be extra explicit, use the `-draftmessage` option as well.